# How to limit the ::selection selector?

Tags: css

I want to limit `::selection` to a li. I mean affect on `li` box that contain an `a` tag.

```
<ul class="report-box">
    <li>
        <a class="password">our pass: www.mysite.com</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want clients when selecting the password with the mouse `::selection` to become red. By default for whole the page, it’s blue.

```
::selection {
    background: #03a9f4;
    color: #fff;
}
li .report-box ::selection  {
    background: #03A9F4;
    color: #fff;
 }
```

Sorry, I am new in CSS. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: i mean I dont want to use ::selection  {
    background: #03A9F4;
    color: #fff;
} for all part of element of page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't give a space between attributes while defining selector

```
div .report-box::selection  {
    background: #03A9F4;
    color: #fff;
}
```

with a space the selector will apply to all child elements of div and report-box class.

Also if the report-box class is meant to be on div you can just remove the space between div and report-box too like

```
div.report-box::selection  {
```

**demo**

```css
div.report-box::selection  {
    background: orange;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="report-box">Some test</div>
```

Comment: Moreover, if that class is meant to be on the div, the space there would need to be removed.